# Typography: What is this glyph called and why is it not used?

Tags: typography

I hope this to be a simple question. It revolves around the letter G.
In LaTeX, the glyph G is often represented as you seen printed here (G) ± serifs or as a script G, resembling:[image]

However there is an alternative to this type of G and it is the cursive G (personal up-right variant):
[image]

which is used in a select subset of fonts and on some logos (e.g. General Mills).

My question is does this cursive G have a name other than alternate G or cursive G? Many fonts have alternate glyphs (especially for the lowercase letter a).

Since typography is about making works legible, is there a reason or stigma about using this type of G?

For fun here is a modernized Kurrent G:
[image]

Comment: Would not this question be more appropriate on [Graphic Design.sx](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @ebo putatively. However this isn't so much about designing a G, it is about its use in documents...

Comment: the style of alphabetic glyphs used in math is heavily affected by tradition.  for the earliest publications, there were not so many fonts available, and making new ones was a significant undertaking.  the shape you cite is probably a 20th century creation, and almost certainly created as a logo, not as an element of a full alphabet.  a font containing only one letter isn't much use to a math/technical publisher.  in this case, there might also be trademark/copyright implications.

Comment: @barbarabeeton actually the cursive G that I am referring to is / was taught following the D'Nealian method in most elementary schools. It was not developed by a brand -- although it is used by one (like all letters). A quick glance at a Google Image search "cursive G" yields about 50% of the G's being as the one imaged above...

Comment: @barbarabeeton it may have been introduced by either Austin Norman Palmer around 1888 or Donald Neal Thurber in 1976, in which case it slightly would predate the 20th century.

Comment: the shape you show is clearly related to, but does not exactly match either the palmer or d'nealian shapes as shown in wikipedia images.  (both of those have a more distinctly rightward lean, and sharper angles.  i was taught the palmer script, and though i recognize your letter, it would not have been graded well by my handwriting instructors. this is not meant as a criticism of your shape, only a comment on the strictness of my teachers, who would certainly flunk my current handwriting.)  submitting this for publication nowadays, it would likely be changed for something more "available".

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes, this variant is meant to be written up right rather than the traditional slant, as mathematical constants are written up write and often symbols which represent collections (e.g. matrices, sets, etc tend to be bold and up-right)

Comment: is this an american thing? I'm a Native English speaker and used to seeing various font styles, I'd recognise a Fraktur G if pushed, but I would never have guessed this was a G, I'm pretty sure I've never seen any document using such a script. (This is to answer your legibility question)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle apparently it is an American thing :P